# How can I track down ADO.NET connection pool issues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ado.net

We have an ASP.NET Core application that is experiencing what appears to be some database connection pool issues that I do not understand.

This application was originally built targeting the .net framework. Recently we updated to ASP.NET Core 3.1 which required us to targeted .NET core. At the same time, we made a pass over a fairly large underlying library to make many paths use async/await that were synchronous previously, including all or nearly all the paths to the database. The database communication is using System.Data.SqlClient (NOT the newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient).

The result of these changes was a relatively large performance gain in response times when a low number of concurrent requests are made with net loss in performance when more load is applied.
What we are observing is a bottleneck in the database connections. Performance is better until we hit the connection pool limit and then things start getting much worse. Increasing the application maximum connection pool size defers the issue. We were not hitting the connection pool limits before the changes with the same tests.

While some overhead in hitting this connection pool limit is not unexpected, the difference we are seeing certainly is. We would expect that at worse the average over the load test for the response time to be about the same, however we are seeing gains in average response time for a modest load tests between 25% and 90% depending on which type of objects we are interacting with in our system.

We were already aware of some ways to mitigate the issue, particularly we know we are being aggressive with database calls. What we are missing is why the bottleneck was introduced and how we can further investigate/mitigate the issue without a vast design rework or rollback.

Comment: are you asking a question?

Comment: SQL Server is multithreaded and adding threads is c# I do not think helps the performance and may make it worse.  The Time to execute a query depends on 1) The size of the database 2) The memory in the Database 3) The Amount of Data being returned. 4) The organization of the database and how badly the database is fragmented.  A SQL Server should be the fastest machine the you can purchase and load it with as much memory that is available.  Add Async methods in c# could just be overloading the Server and cause more process swapping in the server and actually be causing loss of performance.

Comment: Worth checking that connections are successfully being re-used and not just being left open (i.e. orphaned).